# Cast query returning anonymous type to ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

**This is linq to sql, not entity framework**

I'm trying to call `ToStraceString` on a query that returns an anonymous type, but my cast to ObjectQuery is failing.

Is there some of other way to cast this query to `ObjectQuery`, or is there some other way to grab the generated T-SQL short of starting a SQL Server trace?

```
        var junk = db.SiteProducts
                     .Where(p => p.SiteProductId == SiteProductId)
                     .Select(p => new
        {
            p.SiteProductId,
            ItemSku = p.ItemMaster != null ? p.ItemMaster.ItemSku : "",
            p.AdminDisplayName,
            p.CurrentInventory,
            p.IsFreeGift,
            p.SiteDivisionId,
            p.PrimaryParentSiteCategoryId,
            p.UsesVariantAttributes,
            UsesOmsPz = p.ItemMaster != null ? p.ItemMaster.OmsPzTemplateId.HasValue : false,
            p.HasDetailPage,

            div = p.SiteDivision.AdminDisplayName,
            domain = p.Site.PrimaryDomain
        });


        string str = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)junk).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: @SLaks - how embarrassing.  Right - l2s uses the log property - that explains my trouble googling ... *sigh*

Comment: @SLaks - I'll keep it open in case you were already writing an answer to that effect

Comment: @Adam are you trying to figure out how to do this in LINQ to SQL instead?

Comment: @AhmadMageed - nah - I've got it.  It's been awhile since I used l2s - I forgot about the log property on the context

Comment: @Adam I posted another option as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LINQ to SQL you can use the [DataContext.Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx), or the [DataContext.GetCommand method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) to get the generated SQL:

```
var query = dc.Persons.Take(1);
string generatedSql = dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText;
```

This example returns the following SQL from the AdventureWorks database:

> SELECT TOP (1)
>   [t0].[BusinessEntityID],
>   [t0].[PersonType], [t0].[NameStyle],
>   [t0].[Title], [t0].[FirstName],
>   [t0].[MiddleName], [t0].[LastName],
>   [t0].[Suffix], [t0].[EmailPromotion],
>   [t0].[AdditionalContactInfo],
>   [t0].[Demographics], [t0].[rowguid] AS
>   [Rowguid], [t0].[ModifiedDate] FROM
>   [Person].[Person] AS [t0]

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectQuery` is an Entity Framework type.

You can't use it with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Can you just mention the log property on the l2s context so this is useful to anyone seeing this later